# How to search multiple names for the right ID excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to pull the ID of individuals based on their first and last names. I have about 800 names I will need to search from. This needs to be pulled weekly and not everyone shows up each week.

I split the names into first and last names using the Text to Columns function in excel data so its not the neatest.

My data looks something like this

[image]

The function is am using is this =INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,B:B,0)). How can I get excel to search the rest of the jones and pull back the right IDs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do this. One option is the filter function.

```
=FILTER(A:A,(B:B=E2)*(C:C=F2))
```

Comment: What version do I need to get the filter function?

Comment: The FILTER function is only available in Excel for Microsoft 365, Excel 2021, and (I have heard) Excel Online.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you're using an older version of Excel without the `FILTER()` function

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(E2&F2,$B$2:$B$7&$C$2:$C$7,0))
```

which should be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula).

Comment: Hmm. 
Thats not working for me. I wonder if I have it written wrong. This is how it actually translates in my document:=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$677,MATCH(B2&C2,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$677&Sheet1!$C$1:$C$677,0))

Comment: u have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering the formula.. | alternatively, u may refer to https://exceljet.net/formulas/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria for more elobolarive steps